# vagrant port forwarding does not work

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, openstack, devstack

I installed a precise32 VM using Vagrant in which I am trying to employ devstack for openstack developing. In order to access the service from host, I set up some forward ports in configure file but it does not work. That is I can not connect to 10.0.2.15 to which devstack prompted me to connect. I tried to switch the networking mode in VirtualBox from NAT to Bridge, then an error popped out saying something like "the NAT name already exists". I checked out the VirtualBox documentation but did not really understand. Anybody help me out please...

I add following to vagrant configure file:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
config.vm.forward_port 80, 9090
config.vm.forward_port 5000, 5000
config.vm.forward_port 5672, 5672
config.vm.forward_port 3333, 3333
config.vm.forward_port 8773, 8773
config.vm.forward_port 8774, 8774
config.vm.forward_port 8776, 8776
config.vm.forward_port 8777, 8777
config.vm.forward_port 9191, 9191
config.vm.forward_port 9292, 9292
config.vm.forward_port 35357, 35357
config.vm.forward_port 40529, 40529
config.vm.forward_port 47117, 47117
config.vm.forward_port 55977, 55977
config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 8192]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple ports to be exposed (port forwarding), it'll be better off using bridged.

Basically you need to enable Public Network in the `Vagrantfile`, add the following to the config block

```
config.vm.network "public_network"
```

See doc: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/public_network.html

> NOTE: you can leave the default NAT there, vagrant will add a 2nd virtual network adapter.

Once `vagrant up` completes, `vagrant ssh` into the box and do a `ifconfig -a` to get the IP address of the 2nd interface, you should be able to access the services from the host (as they are within the same network / LAN) as long as they bind not only to loopback.

Comment: Still not working...However，I tried enable the private network. It works if I enter 192.168.33.xx which is the static IP assigned. But the port forwarding still not working. I entered 127.0.0.1:9090 in my browser and got a "not available" page.

Comment: You are mixing network modes. Port forwarding is ONLY for NAT. Private in Vagrant is Host-only, the host should access it using the ip address 192.168.33.xx in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I use Vagrant Version 2 with the precise32 vm and use port forwarding successfully as indicated by their [documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html)

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
   config.vm.box = "precise32"
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 1234
end
```

Then I access using `localhost:1234`

Hope this helps.